# Looking for an old anime I saw on Animax as a kid

Tags: princess-sarah

There was this one anime that used to air on Animax quite often when I was a kid. It was this story about a girl who was from a rich family (not too sure about that) who goes through some sort of tragedy and is then forced to work as a maid at an all-girls boarding school with a really strict and unreasonable warden. The girl was fair, she had long, black hair and she almost always used to wear this greenish dress. It was set in Europe somewhere (possibly old England). Drawing style was almost "cartoonish" (very little shading and all). If it helps, some of the anime's that used to air around the same time as this were Astro Boy, InuYasha, ExRider, Saber Marionette, Detective School Q, etc. Any help greatly appreciated. ^__^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounded like the novel *A Little Princess* to me, so I searched to see if there was an anime based on that. Turns out there is one called [Princess Sarah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Sarah), and apart from the green dress, it seems to match your description. (The protagonist does wear a green-ish dress in some of the pictures I've seen from the anime while searching for this, but she doesn't in a couple of them.) I am also not sure if the anime series aired at around the right time.

Comment: Haha, well this does seem to be it. Thanks. Its probably not the same time period as the rest since I watched this as a kid when it aired in India. Nothing airs in India on time -.- Thanks again :D

Answer (score 6):

This series is called [Little Princess Sara](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=444) which is an anime adaptation of Frances Hodgson Burnett's novel "A Little Princess". It is the 11th series in the [World Masterpiece Theater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Masterpiece_Theater) collection. When Sara becomes a maid she is always wearing a dark green dress.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's it! I've been looking for it for sooo damn long. Thanks! :D ^__^

Comment: Amazing site you peeps have here, by the way! And speedy replies too! :)